# What's a good example of showcasing the advantage of gnupg2 over gnupg?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

- Q1) What's a good example of showcasing the advantage of gnupg2 over gnupg?
- Q2) I'm trying to build encryption into a small piece of software for *internal* project management. Is gnupg a good tool to use for that? Is gnupg2 better for any reasons?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GNUpg website](http://www.gnupg.org/)

> GnuPG comes in two flavours: 1.4.11 is the well known and portable standalone version, whereas 2.0.18 is the enhanced and somewhat harder to build version.

The [release notes](http://www.gnupg.org/download/release_notes.en.html) say

> 1.4.11 is the stable version of GnuPG. (2.0.18 is the unstable development version).

For 2.0

> GnuPG-2 has a different architecture than GnuPG-1 (e.g. 1.4.5) in that
>   it splits up functionality into several modules.  However, both
>   versions may be installed alongside without any conflict.  In fact,
>   the gpg version from GnuPG-1 is able to make use of the gpg-agent as
>   included in GnuPG-2 and allows for seamless passphrase caching.  The
>   advantage of GnuPG-1 is its smaller size and the lack of dependency on
>   other modules at run and build time.  We will keep maintaining GnuPG-1
>   versions because they are very useful for small systems and for server
>   based applications requiring only OpenPGP support.

If you read through the notes for each release you will build up a good picture of what features are in 2.x that are not in 1.x. E.g. support for smart-cards.

Comment: I actually read these before positing. But I was looking for some concrete use case to show the advantage/drawback of either.